# item version history to create items with Date field

Tags: content-search, content-tree, content

We have requirement to show some text content (rich text field) based on revision date updated (date field).
Latest updated content (sorted by date in descending) will be shown at the top .
So content authoring will like , next month when I want to create new content with different date , he/she will be interested in creating new content and publish, so the webpage should take care of showing new record at the top and old ones at the bottom in descending order

Maximum number of records could go up to 50-80 in a folder.

Trying to find best possible solution to create these kind of items in sitecore.

Note- These data will be be fetched by search API(using solr, Sitecore version 10.3)
currently identified solution is

1. Maintain same item version history to show different records( need to check if solr can return all versions of an item and any other drawback of this aproach)

Please let me know if there is any drawbacks of this approach.
Thank you!

Comment: Hey, this question doesn't really have a single answer, you are going to get multiple opinions on what is "best". Might be better to have a conversation in the community forums or Slack.

Comment: @RichardSeal - updated the question specific to Item versions. Could you reopen the question?